# How to do calculations on a column of a data frame using values contained in another data frame in R?

Tags: r, database, dataframe, dplyr, calculated-columns

I have 2 data frames: one with experimental data and one with values of some constants. Experimental data and constants are separated by categories (a and b). I would like to include a new column in the experimental data frame that is the result of the following calculation:

z = k*y

To do this, I'm using the `dplyr` package and the `mutate()` function, but I'm not getting the expected result. Does anyone have any tips or suggestions, even if it is necessary to use another package?

```
library(dplyr)

Category <- c("a", "b")
k <- c(1, 2)

# Data frame with the constants for each category
Constant <- data.frame(Category, k)

x <- seq(0,5,1)

df <- expand.grid(x = x,
                  Category = Category)

# Data frame with the experimental resultas
df$y <- seq(1,12,1)

# Failed attempt to calculate z separated by categories
df %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  mutate(z = Constant*y)
```

Comment: Sounds like you just want to make Category a factor variable with labels defined by k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dplyr you can do the following:

```r
library(dplyr)

left_join(df, Constant, by = c("Category")) %>%
  mutate(z = k * y) %>%
  select(-k)
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
a = c()
for(i in unique(df$Category)){
  a = c(a,df[df$Category==i,"y"]*Constant[Constant$Category==i,'k'])
}
df$z=a
```

result:

```
   x Category  y  z
1  0        a  1  1
2  1        a  2  2
3  2        a  3  3
4  3        a  4  4
5  4        a  5  5
6  5        a  6  6
7  0        b  7 14
8  1        b  8 16
9  2        b  9 18
10 3        b 10 20
11 4        b 11 22
12 5        b 12 24
```

I don't know if it was what you're looking for. Juste keep in mind that this works if your `df` is sorted by the category column

if you don't like for loop, here is a `lapply` version:

```
df$z =unlist( lapply(unique(df$Category), function(i){return(df[df$Category==i,"y"]*Constant[Constant$Category==i,'k'])}))
```

if the data isn't sorted by category:

```
df$z=unlist(lapply(1:nrow(df),function(i){ return(df[i,"y"]*Constant[Constant$Category==df[i,"Category"],'k'])}))
```

Comment: Do you have any tips if the data frame is not organized by category but by another column?

Comment: @DanielValenciaC. could you make it work?

Comment: I did not try. Apparently all my data frames are sorted. Thank you very much for your help